# Python: ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: file too short

Tags: python-3.8

Im a beginner in Python and i try to import a math module but i get the following error and i dont understand what it is about :

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/math.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: file too short

can someone helps me please?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Can you share more information? what math module you try to import? did you installed it using `PIP` before import it?